# urlRouterProvider default value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm configuration my route.js file, and having trouble with otherwise. I can't understand what's happening.

Thats my routerConfig file for my login page:

```
 //app.module.js
'use strict';
(function() {

 angular
.module('app',
[
  'ui.router',
  'toastr',
  'ui.bootstrap'
]
);
})();


//login.route.js
'use strict';
(function() {

angular
.module('app')
.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',  routeConfig]);

function routeConfig($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/informe1');

$stateProvider
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    template: '<user-login></user-login>'
  }).state('informe1', {
    url: '/informe1',
    template: '<informe1></informe1>'
  }).state('informe2', {
    url: '/informe2',
    template: '<informe2></informe2>'
  });
}

})();
```

When clicking login button, if user/pass are correct:

```
 $state.go(location.pathname.slice(1));
```

my urls are:

```
http://localhost:3000/informe1 -> works fine
http://localhost:3000/informe2 -> works fine
http://localhost:3000/informe -> fails, error 

    angular.js:14362 Error: Could not resolve 'informe' from state 'login'
```

how can I define "otherwise" correctly?

Comment: Show your injection for `routeConfig`

Comment: remove the `/` from the state. `state('informe2'` and `state('informe1'`

Comment: edited with suggestios, still doesn't works

Comment: I expected `routeConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider']` with `angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])`, check your dependencies

Comment: ok, my app has a kind of special files structure, edited

Comment: I finally edited ng-click in login button  if($state.get(location.pathname.slice(1))){
              $state.go(location.pathname.slice(1));
            } else {
              $state.go("informe1");
            }        , but still don't find my mistake!

Comment: Show your html code: (1) the scripts that you load, (2) the button / link with `ui-sref` / `ng-href` the problem might be that you are not loading some JS file and your link is not working as intended